# Symfony The annotation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded - Symfony Validation with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-3.4, symfony-validator

We have a legacy app which is not based on symfony. Doctrine is in use and now we would like to add validation to the models. **Seems that the Annotations never get autoloaded, even when "use" statements are in use.**

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property Test\Stackoverflow\User::$Username does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.

Wrote a small demo application to showcase the problem and how we create the entity manager and validation instance.

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/validator"     :   "~3.1"
        , "doctrine/orm"        :   "~2.6.1"
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

// Load Entities, would normally be done over composer since they reside in a package
require_once('test/User.php');
require_once('MyAnnotationTestApp.php');

// create test app
$app = new MyAnnotationsTestApp();
$app->initEntityManager('localhost', 'annotation_test', 'root', 'mysql', 3306);

if(key_exists('test', $_GET)){
    // Create entity and validate it
    $entity = new \Test\Stackoverflow\User();
    $entity->setUsername('StackoverflowUser');

    if($app->testAnnotationWithoutLoading($entity)){
        print "Seems the validation was working without preloading the asserts\n<br>";
    }

    if($app->testAnnotationWithLoading($entity)){
        print "Seems the validation was working because we loaded the required class ourself.\n<br>";
    }

    print "\n<br><br>The question is why the required annotation classes never get autoloaded?";

    }else{

    // Load the validator class otherwise the annotation throws an exception
    $notBlankValidator = new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank();

    print "We have cerated the tables but also had to load the validator class ourself.\n<br>\n<br>";

    // create tables and
    $app->updateDatabaseSchema();
    print sprintf('<a href="%s?test">Now lets run the test</a>', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

**Doctrine user Entity**

```
<?php
namespace Test\Stackoverflow;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 *
 */
class User{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="Id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $Id;

    public function getId(){
        return $this->Id;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", length=80, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $Username;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $Username
     */
    public function setUsername($Username)
    {
        $this->Username = $Username;
    }


}
```

**Demo App with doctrine/validator initialisation:**

```
<?php


final class MyAnnotationsTestApp {

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param string $host
     * @param string $database
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @param integer $port
     * @param array $options
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    public function initEntityManager($host, $database, $username, $password, $port, array $options=null){

        if($this->entityManager){
            return $this->entityManager;
        }

        $connectionString = sprintf('mysql://%3$s:%4$s@%1$s/%2$s', $host, $database, $username, $password, $port);
        $isDevMode = true;
        $dbParams = array(
            'url'               =>  $connectionString
            , 'driver'          =>  'pdo_mysql'
            , 'driverOptions'   =>   array(
                1002 =>     "SET NAMES utf8mb4"
            )
        );

        $cacheDriver = null;

        $config = \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(), $isDevMode, '.cache/', $cacheDriver, false);

        if($cacheDriver){
            $config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cacheDriver);
            $config->setQueryCacheImpl($cacheDriver);
            $config->setResultCacheImpl($cacheDriver);
        }


        $this->entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
        return $this->entityManager;
    }


    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager(){
        return $this->entityManager;
    }



    public function updateDatabaseSchema(){
        $metaData = array();
        $usedEntities = array(
            'Test\Stackoverflow\User'
        );
        foreach($usedEntities as $entity){
            $metaData[] = $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata($entity);
        }

        $tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($this->entityManager);
        $tool->updateSchema($metaData);
        $this->generateProxies($metaData);
    }

    /**
     * Generate all the proxy classes for orm in the correct directory.
     * Proxy dir can be configured over application configuration
     *
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    final public function generateProxies($metaData)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $destPath = $em->getConfiguration()->getProxyDir();

        if (!is_dir($destPath)) {
            mkdir($destPath, 0777, true);
        }

        $destPath = realpath($destPath);

        if (!file_exists($destPath)) {
            throw new \Exception("Proxy destination directory could not be created " . $em->getConfiguration()->getProxyDir());
        }

        if (!is_writable($destPath)) {
            throw new \Exception(
                sprintf("Proxies destination directory '<info>%s</info>' does not have write permissions.", $destPath)
            );
        }

        if (count($metaData)) {
            // Generating Proxies
            $em->getProxyFactory()->generateProxyClasses($metaData, $destPath);
        }
    }


    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface
     */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface
     */
    final protected function getValidator(){
        if($this->validator){
            return $this->validator;
        }
        $this->validator = \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
            ->enableAnnotationMapping()
            ->getValidator();
        return $this->validator;

    }


    /**
     * @param \Test\Stackoverflow\User $entity
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function testAnnotationWithoutLoading(\Test\Stackoverflow\User $entity){
        try {
            print "test to validate the entity without preloading the Assert classes\n<br>";
            $this->getValidator()->validate($entity);
            return true;
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            print "<strong>Does not work since the Asserts classes never get loaded: </strong> Exception-message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n<br>";
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param \Test\Stackoverflow\User $entity
     * @return bool
     */
    final public function testAnnotationWithLoading(\Test\Stackoverflow\User $entity){


        // Here we force the autoloader to require the class
        $notBlankValidator = new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank();

        try {
            print "Loaded the validator manually, will test of it fails now\n<br>";
            $this->getValidator()->validate($entity);
            return true;
        } catch(\Exception $e){
            print "<strong>Was not working: </strong> Exception-message: ".$e->getMessage()."\n<br>";
            print sprintf("<strong>Even when we autoload the class it is not working. Type of assert: %s</strong>\n<br>", get_class($notBlankValidator));
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Found that adding the following lines was solving it but ::registerLoader is deprecated and will removed. What is the prefered way to handle this case? 
    $loader = require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
    
  
  
 \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

Comment: From the doctrine source: deprecated this method is deprecated and will be removed in doctrine/annotations 2.0. autoloading should be deferred to the globally registered autoloader by then. For now  use AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')

Comment: I believe that above is covered by `Doctrine`'s own documentation?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Maybe you can send me a link because i found nothing. Appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, this is what I meant: http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/annotations.html -- The part "To anticipate the configuration section, making the above PHP class work with Doctrine Annotations requires this setup:"

Comment: Thanks @JovanPerovic but this functionality is deprecated and its a workaround for the moment but not a solution which will work in the near future. Thats why i asking if there is a better solution. But thanks, i will use the AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader('class_exists')  for the moment

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using the Symfony Standard Edition, you must update your
> autoload.php file by adding the following code [1]
>
> How are these annotations loaded? From looking at the code you could
> guess that the ORM Mapping, Assert Validation and the fully qualified
> annotation can just be loaded using the defined PHP autoloaders. This
> is not the case however: For error handling reasons every check for
> class existence inside the AnnotationReader sets the second parameter
> $autoload of class_exists($name, $autoload) to false. To work
> flawlessly the AnnotationReader requires silent autoloaders which many
> autoloaders are not. Silent autoloading is NOT part of the PSR-0
> specification for autoloading. [2]

```
// at the top of the file
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

// at the end of the file
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(function($class) use ($loader) {
    $loader->loadClass($class);
    return class_exists($class, false);
});
```

[1] https://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-2-0-rc4-released

[2] https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.6/annotations.html

Comment: Thanks for comment and explanation. Will check it out and add to my code.